# How can i get the updated state value in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pusher, pusher-js

i set the users state with axios data but in useEffect hook whereevery i console.log(users) its show the default state that is [] array. please see the comment for better undarstand.

```js
let [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/chat_user_list').then((res) => {
        setUsers(res.data);
    });
    
    let pusher = new Pusher('api-key-over-here', {
        cluster: 'ap1',
        authEndpoint: "/admin/broadcasting/auth",
        auth: {
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
        },
    });
    let channel = pusher.subscribe(`presence-room`);

    channel.bind("pusher:member_added", (member) => {
        //how can i get the updated users state value over here
        console.log(users); //set the users with axios data but it still return the default state; that is an [] array

    });

}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `axios` call is asynchronous, so it's still being completed while the rest of the code in your `useEffect` continues to run.  If you put the rest of your logic inside your `then` you will have access to `res.data` which is what users will be set to.  Note - since `setUsers` is async also, `users` itself may not be updated when you get to your `pusher` functionality.

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('/chat_user_list').then((res) => {
        setUsers(res.data);
let pusher = new Pusher('api-key-over-here', {
        cluster: 'ap1',
        authEndpoint: "/admin/broadcasting/auth",
        auth: {
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
        },
    });
    let channel = pusher.subscribe(`presence-room`);

    channel.bind("pusher:member_added", (member) => {
        console.log(res.data); 
        // you should have access to updated users here
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: i want to run the code only once. giving the dependency users in useEffect whenever user change its re run the code. and subscricbe again again

Comment: Updated to only run when the component is mounted

Comment: at last i get the users with previous state something like this setUsers(prevUsers)